# I need a form not to clear the fields during a submit for test mode

Tags: php, forms

I'm writing a [php](/questions/tagged/php) form that has a button to test the database connection before proceeding to the next step. The only problem is that running the test, clears the fields. I can put `onsubmit="return false"` at the top of the form, but then the test works fine, but I can't submit the form for its real purpose then. I'm guessing this could be fixed with javascript, but I'm a total noob there and I'm wondering if there is a PHP/HTML way to accomplish this.

Here's the form. The test button runs a test [pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo) connection and gives feedback and the "Next Step >>" button writes the configuration to a file and goes on to the next step.

```
<H2>Please fill in your database credentials</H2>
<form class="form" action="" onsubmit="return false" method="post">
    <label for="dbh">Database Host
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="dbh" value=""></label>
    <br><br>
    <label for="dbu">Database User
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="dbu" value=""></label>
    <br><br>

    <label for="dbp">Database Password
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="dbp" value=""></label>
    <br><br>

    <label for="dbn">Database Name
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="dbn" value=""></label>
    <br><br>

    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="test" value="Test Settings">

    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Next Step >>">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write in $_POST vars in your inputs.

```
  <label for="dbh">Database Host
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="dbh" value="<? if ($_POST['dbh']){ print $_POST['dbh']; } ?>"></label><br><br>

  <label for="dbu">Database User
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="dbu" value="<? if ($_POST['dbu']){ print $_POST['dbu']; } ?>"></label><br><br>

  <label for="dbp">Database Password
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="dbp" value="<? if ($_POST['dbp']){ print $_POST['dbp']; } ?>"></label><br><br>

  <label for="dbn">Database Name
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="dbn" value="<? if ($_POST['dbn']){ print $_POST['dbn']; } ?>"></label><br><br>
```

Comment: depending on your error reporting level, you could enter them in shorthand.
`... value="<?=$_POST['dbx']?>"...`

Comment: I tried 2 different versions of that and got 3 different errors. <? if ($_POST['dbh']){ print $_POST['dbh'] } ?> just printed that text in the form field.  Switching to value="<?php if ($_POST['dbn']){ print $_POST['dbn']; } ?>"> gave me Undefined index: dbh

Comment: Thank you!  In my case I needed the full <?php and a ; at the end and I had to add the !empty, so mine look like this...  value="<?php if (!empty($_POST['dbh'])){ print $_POST['dbh']; } ?>">

Comment: Bah I forgot semicolons.  Sorry.

Comment: Actually. That broke everything. No matter what I put in the fields I get the success message where before it was doing a proper test.  what could I be missing there?

Comment: Sure. I am going to confirm that my form works without that code and I'll repost.

Comment: I think I had some other logic issue! I'm good. Thanks for your help!